# Redirect Magento site not working

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, .htaccess

Below is description with Example :

I have 2 sites **www.severnsaleslabequip.com** and **www.qualimet.co.uk** with same **admin (backend )**.

Now **www.qualimet.co.uk** site is no longer to needed so I want to redirect it to **www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html** using index.php or .htaccess.

Right now I am using index.php file to redirect site but it's not working perfect.

I have placed below code to my index.php file to redirect site

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "qualimet.co.uk") {  
header('Location: http://www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html');
die;
$mageRunCode = "qualimet";
$mageRunType = "website";
}
```

So when I enter url **www.qualimet.co.uk** it should be redirect to **www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html** but not in my case.

And if I want to redirect site using .htaccess how can I do?

So please show me both the way (**using index.php and .htaccess**) to redirect site.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have add below code to my .htaccess (**on magento root path) file.

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://www.qualimet.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html [L,R=301]
```

But when I enter **www.qualimet.co.uk** in url it's go into loop like **http://www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html**

Comment: For this you can use server redirect functionality

Comment: You can write 301 Redirect for the url in you .htacess file as follows - Redirect 301 http://www.qualimet.co.uk http://www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html Make sure this is permanent redirect.

Comment: @TejasShah  check my update in question.

Comment: @User34444 check my update.

Comment: Other option can be from admin > configuration > select scope for  > www.qualimet.co.uk website & add the secure & unsecure url as www.severnsaleslabequip.com for this website as well under Web section. So whenever the qualimet.co.uk is hit it will be redirect to new site.

Comment: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file

Please use these htacess redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect rule has two main issues. Firstly the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable doesn't include the protocol so it will never match anything and secondly the use of `!` at the start tells the rewrite engine to redirect anything that doesn't match the value (which will never match).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.severnsaleslabequip\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html [L,R=301]
```

The above assumes that `www.severnsaleslabequip.com` is the only domain in use and says if it's not this domain redirect to the metallurgy page. Another approach would be to perform the redirect only if the request is on the `qualimet.co.uk` domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wwww\.qualimet\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.severnsaleslabequip.com/index.php/metallurgy-and-microscopy/metallurgy.html [L,R=301]
```

As a minor aside, whilst testing rewrites, I'd always use 302, because otherwise you will likely not be seeing the changes you make as your browser and any proxy can cache the 301. Once you're happy the rewrite works, change it to 302.

Comment: perfect man!!!!